# Re-Format Date with PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have the following value in a variable: 26/03/2011

I'd like to get this in the format: 2011-03-26

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: I recommend the use of Zend.Date (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.date.html)

Comment: @Felipe Cardoso Martins - Although I think there's merit in Zend - I think using an Entire Framework to format a date is massive overkill! :-P

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime failing on mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133703/strtotime-failing-on-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmm) and a **many many many more**. Please use the search function before asking superfluous duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
list($d, $m, $y) = explode("/", "26/03/2011");
echo "$y-$m-$d";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Strangely when I do this I get: 2013-04-03 as the result.

Answer (score 3):

While there are many ways to do this, I think the easiest to understand and apply to all date conversions is:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/n/Y', $date)->format('Y-n-d');
```

It is explicit and you'll never have to wonder about m/d or d/m, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good idea to use the [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function combined with [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

```
$date = explode('/', '26/03/2011');

echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$date[1],$date[0],$date[2]));
```

The reason why this could be a good idea is if you ever want to format the date in a different (more complex) format, say "March 26th, 2011" you could just do:

```
$date = explode('/', '26/03/2011');

echo date('F jS, Y', mktime(0,0,0,$date[1],$date[0],$date[2]));
```